# Windows 10 Boot Camp crashes and gives me "Your computer was restarted because of a problem"

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, crash, kernel-panic

I'm logged into Windows 10 Boot Camp before bed. In the morning I find my computer has shut down and has booted into macOS. This must be happening for some reason (perhaps Windows 10 shuts down due to updates. Perhaps it crashes and subsequently boots into the regular Boot OS). Upon waking up I start my computer and boot into Windows 10 again. Once I get the login screen, pressing any of the keyboard keys or the trackpad causes the laptop fans to spin at max for about half a second and then the computer shuts down. It then boots into macOS and I get the infamous "Your computer was restarted because of a problem". This is the crash report on my MacBook Pro 16 inch. I get it almost everyday. Can someone diagnose what's happening?

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff028a8fdc4): PUP PANIC - deserialize: saved state does not match current state. serialization cursor 0x2c9bc - pup-workloop(1)
deserialize: saved state does not match current state. serialization cursor 0x2c9bc
RTKit: RTKit_iOS-1264.100.25.release - Client: not set
!UUID: 9c2abfbb-4f58-3c57-9bf5-c2a73d26bffc
Time: 0x000000005277b4b3

Faulting task stack frame:

Faulting task   0 Call Stack: 0x00000000000157ce 0x00000000000153f2 0x000000000000b86a 0x000000000000b3e8 0x000000000000b278 0x0000000000002b5e 0x0000000000003368 0x0000000000015a62 0x000000000000fcb4
Mailbox (0): (0)
  Inbox  AKF_KIC_INBOX_CTRL = 0x00027701, AKF_KIC_MAILBOX_SET = 0x00001101
  Outbox AKF_AP_OUTBOX_CTRL = 0x00028801, AKF_AP_MAILBOX_SET  = 0x00000000

    dir   endpoint      timestamp           msg
    ====  ============  ==================  ==================
    [RX]    management  0x00000000339cae2c  0x0030304b0000000b
    [TX]    management  0x00000000339caeec  0x004000000000000b
    [RX]    management  0x0000000037e7b1ec  0x003033f50000000c
    [TX]    management  0x0000000037e7b2ac  0x004000000000000c
    [RX]    management  0x000000003c32b574  0x003037880000000d
    [TX]    management  0x000000003c32b634  0x004000000000000d
    [RX]    management  0x00000000407db938  0x00303b3c0000000e
    [TX]    management  0x00000000407db9f8  0x004000000000000e
    [RX]    management  0x0000000044c8bd34  0x00303f3d0000000f
    [TX]    management  0x0000000044c8be10  0x004000000000000f
    [RX]    management  0x000000004913c0a4  0x003042d100000010
    [TX]    management  0x000000004913c15c  0x0040000000000010
    [RX]    management  0x000000004d5ec4f4  0x0030470200000011
    [TX]    management  0x000000004d5ec5a8  0x0040000000000011
    [RX]    management  0x0000000051a9c97c  0x00304ba400000012
    [TX]    management  0x0000000051a9ca34  0x0040000000000012
RTKit Task List:
    name                    | pri     | stack use   | status     | resource
  0 rtk_ep_work             | 025     |   392/1024  | BLOCKED    | 0x2d530
      0x000000000000f89a 0x0000000000010022 0x0000000000010022 0x00000000000159da 0x000000000000fcb4

* 1 pup-workloop            | 015     |   856/4096  | RUNNABLE   | 0

  2 power                   | 000     |   496/1024  | RUNNABLE   | 0x1b78c
      0x000000000000f89a 0x0000000000015054 0x0000000000014dbe 0x000000000000fcb4

  3 main                    | 015     |   592/4096  | WAITING    | 0x22f90
      0x000000000000f89a 0x000000000000fa74 0x000000000000fa74 0x0000000000009662 0x000000000000d700

- Begin APCIeFirmware crashlog ----

#### MemoryQueue: EFI version 0x00010000 OS version 0x00020001 Bridge version 0x00020001
       Host OS: BootCamp Snonce 676432

#### Connections : 13
Connection: com.apple.BridgeAudio.IntelToARM
  Destination: 0x279b8
  WorkQueue: Dest queue 0x279b8 used 5 free 3 head 20689 tail 20694 aborted 1 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0021:com.apple.BridgeAudio.IntelToARM destination completing 0002
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x27978 free 112 pending 15 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x2b8000 mapped 0xc006b000 length 4096
    SubmissionInfo: index 80 status 106 length 4096 adjusted 4096 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x3d0000
    SubmissionInfo: index 81 status 106 length 4096 adjusted 4096 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x300000
    SubmissionInfo: index 82 status 106 length 4096 adjusted 4096 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x408000
    SubmissionInfo: index 83 status 106 length 4096 adjusted 4096 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x308000
    SubmissionInfo: index 84 status 106 length 4096 adjusted 4096 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x310000
Connection: com.apple.BridgeAudio.ARMToIntel
  Source: 0x27d48
  WorkQueue: Src queue 0x27d48 used 0 free 8 head 20692 tail 20692 aborted 1 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0020:com.apple.BridgeAudio.ARMToIntel source completing 0002
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x27d08 free 127 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x2b0000 mapped 0xc006a000 length 4096
Connection: VHC1HostAsynchronousEvents
  Destination: 0x280d8
  WorkQueue: Dest queue 0x280d8 used 0 free 8 head 25280 tail 25280 aborted 25280 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0019:VHC1HostAsynchronousEvents destination completing 0006
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x28098 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x2a0000 mapped 0xc0068000 length 8192
Connection: VHC1HostInterruptEvents
  Destination: 0x28468
  WorkQueue: Dest queue 0x28468 used 0 free 8 head 258 tail 258 aborted 258 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0018:VHC1HostInterruptEvents destination completing 0006
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x28428 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x290000 mapped 0xc0066000 length 8192
Connection: VHC1HostIsochronousEvents
  Destination: 0x287f8
  WorkQueue: Dest queue 0x287f8 used 0 free 8 head 161 tail 161 aborted 161 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0017:VHC1HostIsochronousEvents destination completing 0006
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x287b8 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x280000 mapped 0xc0064000 length 8192
Connection: VHC1HostSystemEvents
  Destination: 0x28b88
  WorkQueue: Dest queue 0x28b88 used 0 free 8 head 161 tail 161 aborted 161 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0016:VHC1HostSystemEvents destination completing 0006
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x28b48 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x270000 mapped 0xc0062000 length 8192
Connection: VHC1HostCommands
  Destination: 0x28f18
  WorkQueue: Dest queue 0x28f18 used 6 free 2 head 1851 tail 1857 aborted 1 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0015:VHC1HostCommands destination completing 0006
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x28ed8 free 229 pending 26 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x260000 mapped 0xc0060000 length 8192
    SubmissionInfo: index 58 status 106 length 16 adjusted 16 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x268740
    SubmissionInfo: index 59 status 106 length 16 adjusted 16 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x268760
    SubmissionInfo: index 60 status 106 length 16 adjusted 16 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x268780
    SubmissionInfo: index 61 status 106 length 16 adjusted 16 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x2687a0
    SubmissionInfo: index 62 status 106 length 16 adjusted 16 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x2687c0
    SubmissionInfo: index 63 status 106 length 16 adjusted 16 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x2687e0
Connection: VHC1FirmwareAsynchronousEvents
  Source: 0x292a8
  WorkQueue: Src queue 0x292a8 used 0 free 8 head 7159 tail 7159 aborted 7159 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0014:VHC1FirmwareAsynchronousEvents source completing 0013
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x29268 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x250000 mapped 0xc005e000 length 8192
Connection: VHC1FirmwareInterruptEvents
  Source: 0x29728
  WorkQueue: Src queue 0x29728 used 0 free 8 head 354 tail 354 aborted 354 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0012:VHC1FirmwareInterruptEvents source completing 0011
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x296e8 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x238000 mapped 0xc005a000 length 8192
Connection: VHC1FirmwareIsochronousEvents
  Source: 0x29ba8
  WorkQueue: Src queue 0x29ba8 used 0 free 8 head 1 tail 1 aborted 1 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0010:VHC1FirmwareIsochronousEvents source completing 0009
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x29b68 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x220000 mapped 0xc0056000 length 8192
Connection: VHC1FirmwareSystemEvents
  Source: 0x2a028
  WorkQueue: Src queue 0x2a028 used 0 free 8 head 3646 tail 3646 aborted 3646 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0008:VHC1FirmwareSystemEvents source completing 0007
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x29fe8 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x208000 mapped 0xc0052000 length 8192
Connection: gOSEffaceableMessageQueue
  Source: 0x2a598
  WorkQueue: Src queue 0x2a598 used 0 free 8 head 40 tail 40 aborted 1 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0005:gOSEffaceableMessageQueue source completing 0003
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x2a558 free 1 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x1e8000 mapped 0xc004d000 length 64
Connection: OSXEffaceableMessageQueue
  Destination: 0x2a910
  WorkQueue: Dest queue 0x2a910 used 1 free 7 head 40 tail 41 aborted 1 rnonce 0
    SubmissionQueue: Bridge:Submission:0004:OSXEffaceableMessageQueue destination completing 0003
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x2a8d0 free 1 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x1e0000 mapped 0xc0044000 length 64
    SubmissionInfo: index 1 status 106 length 12288 adjusted 12288 committed 0 completed 0
      address 0x1f0000

#### Platform
  Heap size: 1093632  free: 1044632
#### Version: 82.0.1

#### DataMover

#### Completion Queues : 8
Bridge:Completion:0013
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x295f8 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x248000 mapped 0xc005c000 length 6144
      Bridge:Submission:0014:VHC1FirmwareAsynchronousEvents
Bridge:Completion:0011
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x29a78 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x230000 mapped 0xc0058000 length 6144
      Bridge:Submission:0012:VHC1FirmwareInterruptEvents
Bridge:Completion:0009
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x29ef8 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x218000 mapped 0xc0054000 length 6144
      Bridge:Submission:0010:VHC1FirmwareIsochronousEvents
Bridge:Completion:0007
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x2a378 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x200000 mapped 0xc0050000 length 6144
      Bridge:Submission:0008:VHC1FirmwareSystemEvents
Bridge:Completion:0006
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x2a468 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x1f8000 mapped 0xc004e000 length 6144
      Bridge:Submission:0019:VHC1HostAsynchronousEvents
      Bridge:Submission:0018:VHC1HostInterruptEvents
      Bridge:Submission:0017:VHC1HostIsochronousEvents
      Bridge:Submission:0016:VHC1HostSystemEvents
      Bridge:Submission:0015:VHC1HostCommands
Bridge:Completion:0003
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x2ac60 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x1d8000 mapped 0xc004b000 length 6144
      Bridge:Submission:0005:gOSEffaceableMessageQueue
      Bridge:Submission:0004:OSXEffaceableMessageQueue
Bridge:Completion:0002
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x2ad50 free 255 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x1c8000 mapped 0xc0049000 length 6144
      Bridge:Submission:0021:com.apple.BridgeAudio.IntelToARM
      Bridge:Submission:0020:com.apple.BridgeAudio.ARMToIntel
Bridge:Completion:0000
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x2af38 free 31 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x1b8000 mapped 0xc0045000 length 768
      Bridge:Command:0001

#### Command Queues
Bridge:Command:0001
    MemoryQueue: IOBC data 0x2ae58 free 31 pending 0 rnonce 0
    DirectSharedObj: physical 0x1c0000 mapped 0xc0046000 length 2048

---- End APCIeFirmware crashlog ----


Sleep Count: 593492
Wake Count:  9
Duty Cycle:  27

RTBuddy(AP): Debug info:
_iopStatus = 0x7
_powerStateChangeInProgress = false
Mailbox Status:
IDLE_STATUS: 0x0000006f
MAILBOX_SET: 0x00000000
MAILBOX_CLR: 0x00000000
INBOX_CTRL: 0x00027701
OUTBOX_CTRL: 0x00029901
AP->IOP Mailbox Log:
Timestamp          | Dir  | Message
0x0000007a273c0de8 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a273c0e18 | [RX] | 0x00400000000000fd 0x0010230000000000
0x0000007a2b86b998 | [TX] | 0x0030b952000000fe 000000000000000000
0x0000007a2b86bc08 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a2b86bc34 | [RX] | 0x00400000000000fe 0x0010340000000000
0x0000007a2fd1be04 | [TX] | 0x0030bd91000000ff 000000000000000000
0x0000007a2fd1c08c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a2fd1c0c8 | [RX] | 0x00400000000000ff 0x0010450000000000
0x0000007a341cc1b8 | [TX] | 0x0030c15700000100 000000000000000000
0x0000007a341cc424 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a341cc450 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000100 0x0010560000000000
0x0000007a3867c560 | [TX] | 0x0030c4ce00000101 000000000000000000
0x0000007a3867c7dc | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a3867c818 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000101 0x0010670000000000
0x0000007a3cb27778 | [TX] | 0x003076fa00000102 000000000000000000
0x0000007a3cb279f0 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a3cb27a2c | [RX] | 0x0040000000000102 0x0010780000000000
0x0000007a40fd7b10 | [TX] | 0x00307ab900000103 000000000000000000
0x0000007a40fd7d78 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a40fd7db0 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000103 0x0010890000000000
0x0000007a45487ef0 | [TX] | 0x00307e8500000104 000000000000000000
0x0000007a45488180 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a454881b4 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000104 0x00109a0000000000
0x0000007a499387c0 | [TX] | 0x0030879400000105 000000000000000000
0x0000007a4993898c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a499389ac | [RX] | 0x0040000000000105 0x0010ab0000000000
0x0000007a4b1b8738 | [TX] | 0x5000000000000000 0x0000000000000007
0x0000007a4b1bc500 | [TX] | 0x00b0000000000201 000000000000000000
0x0000007a4b1bc6fc | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a4b1bc718 | [RX] | 0x00b0000000000201 0x0010bc0000000000
0x0000007a4b1bd7cc | [TX] | 0x0060000000000201 000000000000000000
0x0000007a4b1bda94 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a4b1bdaac | [RX] | 0x0070000000000201 0x0010cd0000000000
0x0000007a4baa1998 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a4baa19c4 | [RX] | 0x00100000000a0003 0x0010010000000000
0x0000007a4baace74 | [TX] | 0x00200000000a0003 000000000000000000
0x0000007a4baacfac | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a4baacfd4 | [RX] | 0x00800000000000df 0x0010120000000000
0x0000007a4bab3e98 | [TX] | 0x00800000000000df 000000000000000000
0x0000007a4bab41cc | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a4bab41ec | [RX] | 0x0070000000000020 0x0010230000000000
0x0000007a4bab4938 | [TX] | 0x00b0000000000020 000000000000000000
0x0000007a4bab4c50 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a4bab4c70 | [RX] | 0x00b0000000000020 0x0010340000000000
0x0000007a4bac8a30 | [TX] | 0x5400000000000000 0x0000000000000007
0x0000007a4bac8c4c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a4bac8c80 | [RX] | 0x5400000000000000 0x0010450000000007
0x0000007a4ff64d2c | [TX] | 0x00304cc600000000 000000000000000000
0x0000007a4ff64fbc | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a4ff64fec | [RX] | 0x0040000000000000 0x0010560000000000
0x0000007a5441236c | [TX] | 0x0030231a00000001 000000000000000000
0x0000007a544125d4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a54412604 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000001 0x0010670000000000
0x0000007a588c284c | [TX] | 0x003027df00000002 000000000000000000
0x0000007a588c2a0c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a588c2a3c | [RX] | 0x0040000000000002 0x0010780000000000
0x0000007a5cd72c00 | [TX] | 0x00302ba000000003 000000000000000000
0x0000007a5cd72e00 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a5cd72e30 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000003 0x0010890000000000
0x0000007a61223084 | [TX] | 0x0030300100000004 000000000000000000
0x0000007a61223294 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a612232bc | [RX] | 0x0040000000000004 0x00109a0000000000
0x0000007a656d27e8 | [TX] | 0x0030279500000005 000000000000000000
0x0000007a656d2a38 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a656d2a64 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000005 0x0010ab0000000000
0x0000007a69b8345c | [TX] | 0x003033f400000006 000000000000000000
0x0000007a69b83634 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a69b83670 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000006 0x0010bc0000000000
0x0000007a6e0337cc | [TX] | 0x0030377c00000007 000000000000000000
0x0000007a6e033a24 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a6e033a4c | [RX] | 0x0040000000000007 0x0010cd0000000000
0x0000007a724e3b44 | [TX] | 0x00303af200000008 000000000000000000
0x0000007a724e3d84 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a724e3dac | [RX] | 0x0040000000000008 0x0010de0000000000
0x0000007a769929ac | [TX] | 0x0030297400000009 000000000000000000
0x0000007a76992bf4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a76992c20 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000009 0x0010ef0000000000
0x0000007a7ae42d20 | [TX] | 0x00302cd70000000a 000000000000000000
0x0000007a7ae42f70 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a7ae42f98 | [RX] | 0x004000000000000a 0x0010f00000000000
0x0000007a7f2f3098 | [TX] | 0x0030304b0000000b 000000000000000000
0x0000007a7f2f32f0 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a7f2f3318 | [RX] | 0x004000000000000b 0x0010010000000000
0x0000007a837a345c | [TX] | 0x003033f50000000c 000000000000000000
0x0000007a837a36b4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a837a36e0 | [RX] | 0x004000000000000c 0x0010120000000000
0x0000007a87c537e0 | [TX] | 0x003037880000000d 000000000000000000
0x0000007a87c53a34 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a87c53a64 | [RX] | 0x004000000000000d 0x0010230000000000
0x0000007a8c103ba4 | [TX] | 0x00303b3c0000000e 000000000000000000
0x0000007a8c103e44 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a8c103e74 | [RX] | 0x004000000000000e 0x0010340000000000
0x0000007a905b3f9c | [TX] | 0x00303f3d0000000f 000000000000000000
0x0000007a905b4228 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a905b4258 | [RX] | 0x004000000000000f 0x0010450000000000
0x0000007a94a64314 | [TX] | 0x003042d100000010 000000000000000000
0x0000007a94a64560 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a94a64590 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000010 0x0010560000000000
0x0000007a98f14764 | [TX] | 0x0030470200000011 000000000000000000
0x0000007a98f149b4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a98f149e4 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000011 0x0010670000000000
0x0000007a9d3c4bec | [TX] | 0x00304ba400000012 000000000000000000
0x0000007a9d3c4e5c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a9d3c4e88 | [RX] | 0x0040000000000012 0x0010780000000000
0x0000007a9e0a7fe8 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a9e0a801c | [RX] | 0x0010300000160000 0x0010890000000001
0x0000007a092ef1e0 | [TX] | 0x0030f198000000f6 000000000000000000
0x0000007a092ef44c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a092ef474 | [RX] | 0x00400000000000f6 0x0010bc0000000000
0x0000007a0d79f56c | [TX] | 0x0030f52c000000f7 000000000000000000
0x0000007a0d79f7d8 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a0d79f808 | [RX] | 0x00400000000000f7 0x0010cd0000000000
0x0000007a11c4f8d4 | [TX] | 0x0030f895000000f8 000000000000000000
0x0000007a11c4fb14 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a11c4fb3c | [RX] | 0x00400000000000f8 0x0010de0000000000
0x0000007a160ffcac | [TX] | 0x0030fc06000000f9 000000000000000000
0x0000007a160fff0c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a160fff48 | [RX] | 0x00400000000000f9 0x0010ef0000000000
0x0000007a1a5b00d8 | [TX] | 0x00300085000000fa 000000000000000000
0x0000007a1a5b032c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a1a5b0358 | [RX] | 0x00400000000000fa 0x0010f00000000000
0x0000007a1ea6049c | [TX] | 0x00300436000000fb 000000000000000000
0x0000007a1ea6071c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a1ea6074c | [RX] | 0x00400000000000fb 0x0010010000000000
0x0000007a22f10828 | [TX] | 0x003007d7000000fc 000000000000000000
0x0000007a22f10a68 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000007a22f10a98 | [RX] | 0x00400000000000fc 0x0010120000000000
0x0000007a273c0b98 | [TX] | 0x00300b4e000000fd 000000000000000000

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS version: 17P5290
macOS version: Not set
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Thu Apr 30 23:53:45 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.120.31~33/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 7715F68C-C691-3BB5-92A7-F624CBCF7221
iBoot version: iBoot-5540.125.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0xd
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x405060400
PCIeUp link state: 0x89271611
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:     0x0000000020a84000
Kernel text base: 0xfffffff027a88000
mach_absolute_time: 0x7a9e223812
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x5eddf03b 0x0002db08
  Sleep   : 0x5edf4585 0x000115ef
  Wake    : 0x5edf4594 0x000237ba
  Calendar: 0x5edf45cd 0x0000508a

Panicked task 0xffffffe00059b000: 3098 pages, 221 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe000985520, backtrace: 0xffffffe0161cb590, tid: 385
          lr: 0xfffffff02834c878  fp: 0xffffffe0161cb5d0
          lr: 0xfffffff02834c6d4  fp: 0xffffffe0161cb640
          lr: 0xfffffff028467350  fp: 0xffffffe0161cb6f0
          lr: 0xfffffff02891562c  fp: 0xffffffe0161cb700
          lr: 0xfffffff02834c03c  fp: 0xffffffe0161cba70
          lr: 0xfffffff02834c394  fp: 0xffffffe0161cbac0
          lr: 0xfffffff029182934  fp: 0xffffffe0161cbae0
          lr: 0xfffffff028a8fdc4  fp: 0xffffffe0161cbb40
          lr: 0xfffffff028a879d4  fp: 0xffffffe0161cbbb0
          lr: 0xfffffff028a8769c  fp: 0xffffffe0161cbbe0
          lr: 0xfffffff028a753a8  fp: 0xffffffe0161cbc10
          lr: 0xfffffff028883734  fp: 0xffffffe0161cbc50
          lr: 0xfffffff028882fb8  fp: 0xffffffe0161cbc90
          lr: 0xfffffff028920514  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the mac into the mac os before sleep to see if it reboots overnight ie isolate if it is windows only related?

Comment: I'm getting the same.